# Port Channel with 1x SFP and 1x Copper Port

Tags: networking, cisco, switch

I wondering if it's possible to combinate a sfp port and a copper port into a port channel, if both run on same speed of course.

hardware is a

Cisco Catalyst 2960-48TC-S (lan lite image)
and
Cisco Catalyst 2960g-24TC-L (lan base)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with Cisco wants me to say that speed/duplex are all that should matter. However, I've yet to come across this type of setup so I cannot say with 100% certainty that IOS will allow it.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem. I did this with several other vendors (Foundry, HP, Extreme, ...) and Cisco should not be a problem, too.

Don't rely 100% on the syntax, tho.

`conf t

int g0/0

desc Copper Port

speed 1000

duplex full

channel-proto lacp

channel-group 1 mode active

exit

int g0/1

desc SFP

channel-proto lacp

channel-group 1 mode active
end`